# Alt + Tab On button Click in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to operate 'Alt + Tab' function on button click event in VBNet. Below Is what I have tried but it doesn't work all the time. I want to toggle between selected applications which user will select in Listbox.

```css
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}")
```

Comment: The AltTab won't work in this case. When you select your application in the listbox it doesn't mean when AltTab is used it will switch between them. Look into Win32 API findwindow and setforegroundwindow...

Comment: What if I want to simply switch from one window to another like standard Alt + Tab on button click event

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyz95fhy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant that's fine assuming the listbox items have the exact title of the window...

Comment: AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad") not working. Not activating my window

Comment: @Codexer - I would hope he does it correctly, separates the data from the view and uses the process ID instead so this can never fail.